# r: %*% and lapply/mapply when arguments are reversed

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have been wondering the most efficient way to do matrix multiplication on lists.

Let's say I have a matrix `A` and a `list` of matrices `B`:

```
A = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol=2, nrow=2)
B = list(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol=2, nrow=2), matrix(c(4,3,2,1), ncol=2, nrow=2))
```

And I want the list of crossproducts of `A` and each element `b` of `B`:

```
A %*% b
```

I was trying to use `lapply()` but couldn't figure out how to ensure the right sequence of multiplication without extra nested `lapply`'s to transpose each `b`...

```
lapply(B, '%*%', A) # which gives a list of b%*%A rather than A%*%b
lapply(lapply(lapply(B, t), '%*%', t(A)), t) # gives the answer but geez...
```

Could anyone kindly give me some pointers here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your `function` inside `lapply()`, like so

```
lapply(B, function(x) A%*%x)
```